# how to use Timer with serial port

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to develop gui with `wxpython` by using serial port. But I need to use serial port resource concurrency for saving data all times and plotting graphics. For this, I used `wx.Timer` but couldnt succeed on it. The below code just sample:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM9',9600)
def update(self, event):
        global ser
        timerId = event.GetId()         
        if timerId == TIMER_ID1:
            print("hello")
            for line in ser:
                print(line)
            print("world")         
        else:            
            x=[]
            x1=[]
            x2=[]
            y=[]
            y1=[]
            y2=[]
            i=0
            #fig = plt.figure()               
            def sV_sat(i):     
                for line in ser:
                    data=line.split(b",")                  
                    if data[0] == b"$GPGSV":
                        print("c")
                        sView_GP = data[3]
                        sNumber_GP = data[4]
                        i=i+1
                        x.append(i)
                        #x=[i]                         
                        y.append(float(sView_GP))
                        ax.set_title("GPS")
                        ax1.set_title("GPS-GLO")
                        ax1.set_ylim(0,20)

                        ax.bar(i,y,color='green')         #only GPS      #option 2
                        ax1.plot(x,y,'g')      #GPS ve ...

                    #time.sleep(0.1)                
            ani8 = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,sV_sat)
            plt.legend()
            #pyplot.show() 
            plt.show()
        print (time.ctime())
```

The above code gave me graphics but it couldn't give `print(line)`:(9th line)

```
print("hello")
for line in ser:
    print(line)
print("world")
```

Just print: `hello` and `world` with graphics

```
hello
world
```

The second serial line(line 21) give me graphics. Thats ok. Why first one(line 8) is skipped? Any helps will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: please make a minimum working example that reproduces the problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: actually it doesnt give any error. But when i try to use serial, second one(line 19) give me graphics. Thats ok. Why first one(line 6) is skipped? Thats my problem actually.

Comment: we don't have any idea what `ser` is ,but my first guess would be that `ser` is an empty list and there's nothing to iterate over

Comment: sorry for that ser=serial.Serial('COM9',9600)...just edited on question

Answer (score 0):

Just reading the documentation for pySerial suggests that you have to `read` the serial port.
i.e.

> Open named port at “19200,8,N,1”, 1s timeout:

```
>>> import serial
>>> with serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS1', 19200, timeout=1) as ser:
...     x = ser.read()          # read one byte
...     s = ser.read(10)        # read up to ten bytes (timeout)
...     line = ser.readline()   # read a '\n' terminated line
```

Open port at “38400,8,E,1”, non blocking HW handshaking:

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 38400, timeout=0,
...                     parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, rtscts=1)
>>> s = ser.read(100)       # read up to one hundred bytes
...                         # or as much is in the buffer
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but i dont have any problem with serial because second serial line are working with no problem and give graphics. I mean why i couldnt achieve the serial port more than once?